# React Native Expo: Network Error when Sending File via FormData in a Form

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, axios, expo

### Issue: Network Error when Sending File via FormData in React Native Expo

#### Problem Description

I'm encountering an issue when trying to send a file via FormData in a React Native Expo project. The goal is to upload a PEM file using axios, but I'm consistently receiving a "Network Error" with a status code of 0. Additionally, on the backend, the request is not being received.

#### Code

```
const sendFormData = async () => {
    const pemString = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n...'; // Example
    const file = new File([pemString], 'pem');
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('pem', file);

    const res = await axios.post('BASE_URL/upload', formData, {
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        },
    });

    console.log('res', res); // [AxiosError: Network Error]
};
```

Additional Information

- The issue only occurs when attempting to send a file; sending plain text data is successful.
- I've tested the same request in a regular front-end environment, and it works as expected. The problem seems to be specific to React Native Expo.

Observations

- Status Code: 0
- Backend does not receive the request when attempting to send a file.
- Successful when sending other data types, like plain text.

Attempts

- I've tried using the fetch API, but the issue persists.
- The FormData construction and headers are consistent with successful requests in regular front-end environments.

Environment

- React Native Expo
- axios library
- Testing on a physical device

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I attempted to upload a PEM file in a React Native Expo project using the provided sendFormData function. I expected a successful file upload with a non-zero status code, and for the backend to receive the file. However, I consistently encountered a "Network Error" with a status code of 0. Other data types, such as plain text, are successfully sent and received

Comment: You dont mention what you are using server side? Simply uploading to BASE_URL/upload without executing something like PHP to handle the file it simply wont do anything? Try using something like FileSystem.uploadAsync with a script to hanlde the form data.

Comment: Please tell full path of file. And tell which app created that file.

Comment: @JulesUK Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, I can't control the backend, and this specific request doesn't seem to impact it. Surprisingly, it works seamlessly from the front-end.

As a mobile app beginner, I'm still exploring. I've looked into FileSystem for file uploads but lack a fileUri for FileSystem.uploadAsync.

Any advice? Appreciate your time!

Comment: @blackapps I obtain the PEM file dynamically from another endpoint in my application, so it doesn't have a specific file path on the device. Is there a specific approach I should follow in this scenario?

Comment: I dont understand scenario. `new File([pemString], ...` Please then tell value of [pemString]. Where is the file that you received and now want to upload?

Comment: try using the path to where the file should be going where you have BASE_URL/upload. Try just ../upload/ or ./upload/  Do you not have any information regarding this from the provider?